# Как сделать такую страницу?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, интерфейс, веб-программирование

Добырй день, ХэшКод. Недавно увидел в интернете сайт http://www.newinttech.com/. (Логин/пароль: `user/user`). Хотел спросить в вас, может кто-нибудь знаком, с тем какие технологии испоьзовались для написани страницы?
[image]
Просьба давать не односложные ответы в стиле "У тебя, что `google` отключили?" или "это же `jquery`!". А показать какой именно виджет использовался. С `mootools`, `ExtJS` и др. я пока еще не знаком.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитесь пользоваться файрбагом! Открываете страницу, открываете файрбаг и смотрите в тег хеад, для начала. Там длинный список плагинов

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript">
//jquery
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">
//jquery ui
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
//jquery ui календарь с часами
<script src="/js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript">
//валидация форм
<script src="/js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript">
//аяксовая навигация
<script src="/js/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js" type="text/javascript">
//редактор сообщений
<script src="/js/history/jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript">
//хтмл5 история
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-i18n.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/clickmenu.js" type="text/javascript">
//плагин для выпадающего меню
<script src="/js/jquery.scrollto.min.js" type="text/javascript">
//скроллер
<script src="/js/swfupload.js" type="text/javascript">
//флешовый загрузчик файлов
```

Это то, что сразу бросилось в глаза. Но все это вершина айсберга, такие клоны gmail не используют стандартные виджеты, а используют самописный код, который для нормального программиста легче написать самому, чем искать пол дня какой-то плагин.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. 
P.S. Так я и не понял, где они взяли такие красивые иконки и меню..